# Kubernetes Helm PVC

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

I have a yml file where I create a pvc on my provider (digital ocean)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

I am also using a helm chart and want to be able to point to the already created pvc
How can I do this? This helm chart is deployed after the PVC is already created/deployed

```
  master:
    persistence:
      enabled: true
      ## mariadb data Persistent Volume Storage Class
      ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
      ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
      ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
      ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
      ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
      ##
      # storageClass: "-"
      accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      size: 10Gi
```

Comment: Does the helm chart committed somewhere in git, where we can refer? To fix your problem you need to modify your deployment to use existing PVC.

Comment: values are here: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/ghost/values.yaml thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To mount your PVC in your helm chart, do this:

- Disable persistence volume creation in helm chart

```
master:
    persistence:
      enabled: false #Setting it to false
```

- Modify your deployment yaml, its located in templates folder of your helm chart. [Point your Pod to mount your own PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-pod).

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: test-pvc  # pointing to existing test-pvc
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

**Update:**

Specifically in your case, you can specify your pvc name against [existingClaim parameter](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/ghost/values.yaml#L227) in values.yaml, it will be [picked up by your deployment](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/ghost/templates/deployment.yaml#L214-L215).

Comment: Is there a way to just specify the pvc name  in the helm values.yml? In the values file there is also:   ## A manually managed Persistent Volume Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  ##
  # existingClaim:

Comment: Yes you can put the name of your pvc against the `existingclaim` parameter. Updated my answer.

Comment: should I set storageClass or storageClassName?

Comment: ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  # storageClass: "-"

Comment: Storageclass is not required.